# Android: returning the result code

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

In this code from my MainActivity.java

```
public static int sendSMS(String phoneNumber,String message) {    
      SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
      int result_code;

      PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(basecontext, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);

      // ---when the SMS has been sent---
      basecontext.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {                  
              switch (getResultCode()) {
              case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                  result_code = 1;                              
                  break;
              case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                  result_code = 2;                              
                  break;
              case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                  result_code = 3;      
                  break;
              case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:                        
                  result_code = 4;      
                  break;
              case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                  result_code = 5;      
                  break;
              }
          }
      }, new IntentFilter(SENT));
      smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, null);  
 return result_code;                
 }
```

but is says "Cannot refer to a non-final variable result_code inside an inner class defined in a different method".
I did this because ill use it in my AlarmReceiver class like this

```
   public class alarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

           int i = MainActivity.sendSms("6391234123","Hello world");
           if(i==1){some codes here}
           else if(i==2){some codes here}
           ....
           ....
    }
    }
```

For short I don't know how to pass those numbers in result_code and return it if the method is called. Any way to do this? Sorry if I cant ask a good question, and more specific because Im new here and bad english also.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this

```
new BroadcastReceiver() {
```

You're creating a BradcastReceiver class. Inside of this class, you are using result_code, which is outside the inner class. You need to declare result_code as final

```
final int result_code;
```

Regards

PS: As a suggestion, the standard result code when you dont have errors is 0, it would be better to get used to return 0 when things went good

Comment: i got this error when i changed it to final..
"The final local variable result_code cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type"
is there any way to return that result_code when i call the sendSMS method?